# Microsoft Graph API User custom property

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, office365-apps

I need to access custom properties on the user object via the graph api. Currently the documentation shows the properties that can be accessed in the "Update User" section of the v1.0: http://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_update . I'm using this call to get the current logged in user and properties, but I can't seem to get any custom properties to work:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=aboutMe,birthday,city,country,department,displayName,givenName,hireDate,interests,jobTitle,mobilePhone,officeLocation,pastProjects,postalCode,preferredLanguage,preferredName,responsibilities,schools,skills,state,streetAddress,surname,usageLocation,userPrincipalName,userType`

I checked on one of our custom properties that maps back to RefinableString23, but that doesn't seem to want to work. Does anyone know if it's even possible to access custom properties and if so what I may be doing wrong.

Comment: How did you define the custom property that maps to RefinableString23? For the user entity type MS Graph allows to access custom properties defined in the Azure Active Directory (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aadgraphteam/archive/2014/03/06/extend-azure-active-directory-schema-using-graph-api-preview.aspx).

Comment: Not sure how it was mapped as I didn't create it but I will reach out to the team that did and see what answer I can get from them.

Comment: Did you e er get this working?

Answer (score 3):

As well as the extensions that are possible on messages, events and contacts, you can also extend entities such as users and groups through Azure AD, as Marek was suggesting (link to more up to date doc is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions).

Viewing/updating those extension property values is possible through MS Graph API.  Microsoft Graph does not expose a way to register new extensions yet - for that you would still need to use Azure AD Graph API.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I am trying to use a filter query for these extension properties against MS Graph. But somehow it does not seem to work as it does with AAD Graph. Is that not supported in MS Graph? Is there no current way of getting all users with a certain value for a certain extension property?

Comment: There was a bug here, but that has now been fixed.

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT can you be more specific about HOW to use the MS Graph API Client to view the extension property values?  Can't seem to find docs for that!

Comment: We don't really have any docs on that - since it just relies on the standard OData query parameters.  It's identical to how you query in AAD Graph API - using $filter to filter on the value of the extension property.  You can also use $select to select any of the extension properties.  NOTE: we also have a preview of extensibility support natively in Microsoft Graph (which is a bit different and simpler to use than the AAD Graph version).  Find out more here: https://dev.office.com/blogs/adding-customer-data-to-resources-in-Microsoft-Graph-preview.  Love to know what you think.

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT this is a long shot, but using IN operator with an extension property seems not working. For example `&$filter=extension_b2e1d3ab95ac4adf915fcc258ea34c76_ContactId in ('46450218-5c2f-4b4d-94f6-d9a4ac441d75', '46450218-5c2f-4b4d-94f6-d9a4ac441d75')` gives ` "message": "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'elementType')",` 2 days looking around the documentation but nothing seems to come up