# Filter Query failing for Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to perform a filter query against Microsoft Graph (eg):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me?$filter=extension_d8dde29f1095422e91537a6cb22a2f74_skypeId+eq+'joe.smith'
```

But I always receive a similar response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Filter not supported.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "d1b45316-80c9-4ce1-bfe3-3c07a4af42a9",
            "date": "2016-08-25T18:53:45"
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to this with Azure AD Graph, but I want to achieve a similar result with MS Graph:

```
https://graph.windows.net/contoso.com/users/joe@contoso.com?api-version=1.21-preview&$filter=extension_d8dde29f1095422e91537a6cb22a2f74_skypeId+eq+'joe.smith'
```

Is filtering with extension properties not possible with MS Graph? Is there a correct way of doing this or some other substitute query that could help me query for extension properties?

Thanks

Comment: Another related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34725229/microsoft-graph-api-user-custom-property/34772286#comment65662626_34772286

Comment: Sorry - missed that related thread.  It looks like exactly the same issue.  We've filed a bug internally, and hopefully we'll get it fixed soon.

Comment: Great! Thanks for following up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has now been fixed and deployed.
Vishrut - please try your query again and confirm that this is now working for you.

Comment: Awesome! Filter queries on extension properties now work with MS Graph. Thanks for following up :)

Comment: Sorry about the delay.  Good this is now working for you.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce this issue too. But filter the users collection using the build-in property works well for me. It seems that the Microsoft Graph doesn't support to filter the custom property for the users rest API.

You can submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) if you require this feature.